# Capturing of Screen shot starting from 0,0

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am using following code to make a screen shot

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

blendMode:kCGBlendModeClear alpha:1.0];

[self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

return viewImage;
```

It is working fine but it returns the full screen, and I want a screen shot of a particular Frame, like `( 100,100,200,200)`, I tried to make changes in:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
```

But no success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
float x = 100;
float y = 100;
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(200,200);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -x, -y);
[view.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: +1 Thank You man....it was really very very important task to me....and your tricks worked.

Comment: You should start using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 2.0) on retina display devices

Answer (score 0):

just use three line of code.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 480));
    [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *frame= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: No, that captures area of 0,0,320,480. Question was how to crop area of x,y,w,h.