# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext how to set position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, screenshot

I am taking a screenshot in my application. I am able to take the screenshot, but now
I want to take it by specifying the x and y coordinate. I mean taking a screenshot from y=40. Is that possible?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenshot.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5538275/1077722

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenshot.frame.size);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect((CGImageRef)self.view.layer.contents, cropRect);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(...)];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```