# iOS: Convert iOS app screen as network packets

Tags: ios, sockets, network-programming

I am developing an iOS application, where i need to share my iOS application screen converted as network packets into another server destination. I can use socket programming for sending and receiving network packets. But, i want to know, how can it be possible to convert my iOS app native screen (view) to packets? For ex: In windows desktop, its achieved by RDP and video driver converts desktop screen to packets.

Please advise if anyone come across working on such thing.

Thank you.

Getsy.

Comment: Hmm... I doubt you'd get an API for that on iOS. Is transferring [screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538080/capturing-of-screen-shot-starting-from-0-0) acceptable? Then you'd be sending images.

Comment: Hi Shinigamani, Yeah, if no api provides to support packet transferring, then need to look for screenshot streaming methodology. Will it fast? How can i do that way?

Comment: Do you use IOSurface private framework to capture screen? What's the frequency of screen capture? Based on that I may be able to suggest..

Comment: I assume you mean capture the entire screen, even when the app is closed/you are playing with other apps. That's not possible with public APIs, you can only get a snapshot of your own app.

Comment: Hi, I want to do screen sharing of my app screens only, not the any other app.

Comment: Hi Bugivore, This should work like a VNC for example. Whatever i open screens in my app will be streamed to the other end of destop or web app module.

Comment: How about to convert `UIView` in a `UIImage`and then upload it over http?

Comment: Hi  Shinigami, Need more information on screenshot streaming for supporting screen-sharing capabilities(including touch/edit controls) of my iOS app views by a desktop/web app. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Hi @Getsy, I may be late but you can capture screenshot of your app  convert that image into some data format and send that data to server and convert back that data to image and show there.
This links might help you . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically?lq=1

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this, I currently have a working solution, however it requires to much bandwidth to send screenshots one by one. See my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346884/

Answer (score 1):

iOS has native support to mirror the screen to a remote display. It is called AirPlay Mirroring.

It would be very hard to provide a similar experience trying to bypass iOS.
You would have to run in the background. You would have to do some sort of video compression combined with streaming. Apple doesn't give you enough control over their H.264 hardware compressor.

There are multiple products out there to receive the your iOS screen. For example:
http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/ or
http://www.airserver.com/

If you want more control on the receiving side you could write your own AirPlay receiver.
I'd start here: http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html#screenmirroring